# ES6 Generators: poor stack trace from iterator.throw(err)

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

The ES6 method: `iterator.throw(err)` is often described as injecting an exception as though it occurred at the `yield` statement in the generator.  The problem is that the stack trace for this exception does not contain any reference to the file/line for the yield statement or even the function that it is in. Rather, the stack trace seems to only be generated when the exception object is *constructed*, which is not inside the `generator`.

The question is: **how can I get the location of the offending yield statement, in a stack trace or otherwise?**

```
function* one_of_many_generators() {
    // ...
    yield ajax(url);    // <-- what I need in the stack trace
    // ...
}

function outer() {
    var iterator = one_of_many_generators();
    iterator.next();    // runs to the first yield

    // inject exception at the yield statement
    iterator.throw(Error("error"));   // <-- top of stack trace shows here
}
```

Though this issue is not specific to `Promises`, they may make it easier to picture the problem.  In my case, I am using a task system with generators and promises. The hypothetical function `ajax()` returns a Promise, and if that is rejected then the error is converted into a throw at the yield statement using this mechanism.

The stack traces in the debugger are pretty useless because I cannot find a way to get the function, file, or line number for the *`yield statement`* where this injection is occurring.  Calling `iterator.throw(err)` is treated like a rethrow, and does not get new stack information, so it only shows a location inside the `ajax()` function which can be called from many places, and by throwing a new error in `outer()` like in the example above, the same throw line shows for all errors. Neither gives a hint as to what `generator` function was being executed for *debugging* the error.

---

I am using Chrome **v42**.

Comment: If you're using bluebird, there's Promise.coroutine that handles a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: You should file a bug report/missing feature rport for Chrome if you think there is something missing. There is nothing anyone else can do. I would expect may more such bugs in all browsers for everything ES6. http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: Stack traces in JavaScript are always bound to the `Error` instance that you created and will always show in the line that created them. So your stack trace will always show the line where `Error` is called.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum while this is true, it seems to leave a real development problem for non-trivial use of generators. When calling a normal function that throws, the stack at least shows the calling line.  But if a generator waits on a promise that fails, there seems to be no way to find out the "calling" code stack.  If this is not an implementation error, then it seems like a design issue.

Comment: Well, libraries like Bluebird stitch the stack traces manually.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators and promises don't mix very well (yet) - you're essentially yielding a promise that then fails outside the loop.

You can get round this by passing the results of the promise back to the generator, something like:

```
function* one_of_many_generators() {
    // ...
    var promiseResult = yield ajax(url);    // <-- what I need in the stack trace

    // Now we're back in the generator with the result of the promise
    if(notHappyWithResult(promiseResult))
        throw new Error('Reason result is bad');
    // ...
}

async function outer() {
    var iterator = one_of_many_generators();
    let prms = iterator.next();    // runs to the first yield

    // Wait for the promise to finish
    let result = await prms;

    // Pass the result back to the generator
    let whatever = iterator.next(result);
}
```

Only: this is kind of what `async` and `await` do anyway (these keywords being just syntactic sugar for a generator of promises with results passed back) and if you use them a regular `try-catch` will work.

`iterator.throw` is mainly a way of stopping the iteration, not injecting an exception back into it - top of the stack is still wherever you create the `Error`.

Finally, coming soon in Chrome are [async iterators](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/) - these are pretty powerful and are all about iterations of promises.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

```
async function example() {
  const arrayOfFetchPromises = [
    fetch('1.txt'),
    fetch('2.txt'),
    fetch('3.txt')
  ];

  // Regular iterator:
  for (const item of arrayOfFetchPromises) {
    console.log(item); // Logs a promise
  }

  // Async iterator:
  for await (const item of arrayOfFetchPromises) {
    console.log(item); // Logs a response
  }
}
```

In this case, `for-await` takes each item from the `array` and waits for it to resolve. You'll get the first response even if the second response isn't ready yet, but you'll always get the responses in the correct order. You can simply handle the rejection for eg using the same old `.catch` :) But this pattern is known to be prone to unhandled rejections. There's always `Promise.all` ... The Promise.all version is:

```
const [value1, value2] = await Promise.all([getValue1Async(), getValue2Async()]);
```

I also suggest checking out some of these tools: [iter-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iter-tools)